# How to insert URL in an HTML tag on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby beginner developing for Rails 4.

I have a tag like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="URLholder" value=" ??? "/>
```

that I want to add my application **root URL** in the value attribute (instead of ???). How do I do that?

*Note above that I need an input of type hidden*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ERB` templates:

```
# Remember to use double quotes for string interpolation
<%= text_field_tag 'URLholder', "#{root_url}" %>
```

For hidden input types, there is a `FormTagHelper` in Rails called `hidden_field_tag`,

```
# Remember to use double quotes for string interpolation
<%= hidden_field_tag 'URLholder', "#{root_url}" %>
```

Ref: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag

Hope it works :)

Comment: The input tag will be of `type="hidden"`, I couldn't find a helper method that will create one like this for me. Can I just use the option above and set it to `type="hidden"` instead of `type="text"` or something of the kind?

Comment: You did not mention in your question that you want a hidden field. Please make your question clear so that answers could be relevant according to your requirement. Updated my answer as per you wanted.

Comment: Edited. Thank you for your answer, for some reason I couldn't find `hidden_field_tag` in the Rails API documentation so I appreciate you sharing a source for the helper method.